# Create a capture template that asks which heading I want to file the task under

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to create a new capture template in my emacs config (mapped to "t") that allows me to create a new task in a specific file on my hard drive located at "~/Dropbox/org/agenda/tasks.org"

I want the capture template to prompt me to choose which heading to file this task under, and the list of headings should be pulled from that aforementioned tasks.org file. All headings should be included in the list, except for those headings that contain a task keyword such as "TODO" or "DONE." That is, I only want to be able to choose to file the task under non-task headings.

My hope is that I can get a slick selection pop-up buffer using vertico to allow me to select the heading, then type the task in, and then have the task saved to the appropriate place in the buffer.

I've tried several iterations of code to try and do this adapting the org-refile mechanism, but I'm running into a wall because my familiarity with elisp is limited. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to write this function but am getting a `org-capture-set-target-location: Wrong type argument: stringp, 240` error.

```
;; Function to get the list of headings without task keywords
(defun my/org-get-headings-without-keywords ()
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/Dropbox/org/agenda/tasks.org")
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
      (lambda (headline)
        (let ((todo-keyword (org-element-property :todo-keyword headline)))
          (unless todo-keyword
            (org-element-property :raw-value headline))))
      nil t)))

;; Function to set the target location for capture template
(defun my/org-select-heading-and-set-location ()
  (let* ((org-refile-targets `(((, "~/Dropbox/org/agenda/tasks.org") :maxlevel . 9)))
         (org-refile-use-outline-path t)
         (org-refile-allow-creating-parent-nodes 'confirm)
         (org-refile-target-verify-function
          (lambda ()
            (not (member (org-get-todo-state) (list "TODO" "DONE")))))
         (selected-location (org-refile-get-location "Choose a heading:" nil nil)))
    (org-capture-set-target-location (list 'file+headline (car selected-location) (nth 3 selected-location)))))

;; Add the capture template in the after! org block
(after! org
  (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
               '("t" "Task under heading" entry
                 (function my/org-select-heading-and-set-location)
                 "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a"))
  ;; ... other configurations ...
  )
```